# remove img class on thumbnail for sm device

Tags: html, css, media-queries, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have made a thumbnail gallery using various size `.img-circles` on `.img-thumbnails` for the lg, md, and xs widths in Bootstrap - the problem is that I would like to remove the `.img-circle` class for only the sm screen width allowing the `.img-thumbnail` class to remain.

Here is a snippet of HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 thumb">
        <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
            <img src="img/dirk_avatar_thmb.png" class="img-responsive img-circle">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried a few things with media queries - with no results - but I am new to it.
Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this stylesheet

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width:969px) {
.img-circle {
border-radius: 0;
}
}
```

Comment: 992px is the md min width. But this will affect all img-circle at that size.

Comment: Thank you - this is very helpful because it makes it clear that it is just the one property that is driving that style.